# Searching and sorting based on distance

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a PHP & MySql app. Here is what I have and am trying to do:

I have a table with institution profile that contains institution name, postal code, region_id, category and other details. A user can search for an institution based on region_id and category. I can `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE category = 1 and region_id = 1`. I then need to sort the result set on the basis of distance from the user given Postal Code in ascending order. I have an algorithm that converts user postal_code into latlong and find distance from each institutions (I have lat long for each institution in the table).

The problem is that my table is huge. When I search in the above scenario the result set contains around 1000 rows. I then have to find the distance for each row from the user postal_code and then sort it. Now, it is fast on my local but I am pretty sure that when it goes live, it is going to take a lot of time to search, calculate and sort. I then thought of fixing the problem by showing 10 results at a time but it is pretty clear that won't solve since I will still have to calculate the distance and sort before I can present the result.

What do you think is the best approach to this problem? I was thinking in searching with ascending order of lat long but that won't make sense since the lat longs are not linear. The postal codes are Canadian. I don't know if I can leverage that somehow.

Let me know what you guys think. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the way you calculate the distance. If you can do it without running additional queries for each comparison (you should be able to in this case), sorting 1000 rows will be trivial for the server and you need not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try one of these 2 things:

- Use [MySQL spatial support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-introduction.html), it will need changes in your DB schema, but I think it's typical for your case, thus it's performance should be good - supposedly.
- Write the query to calculate the distances in SQL, not in PHP, you don't want a single query to calculate every single distance, right? It will has something like this (a rough version):

  ```
  SELECT ..., sqrt(
      (POW(latitude2 - latitude1, 2)) + 
      (POW(longitude2 - longitude1, 2)) 
   ) AS distance, ...
  ```

Comment: If you are going to use this, you need to replace the formula with one that works with geo coordinates.

Comment: These 2 options are apples and oranges, you've just made a fruit cocktail!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance in the query
(this is a pasudo dode:)

```
sprintf("SELECT placeName, MARKER.lat, MARKER.lng, (6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distanza FROM MARKERtable....
HAVING distanza < '%s'", $lat, $lng, $lat, $distance)
```

where $lat and $lan are current location of user (or address selected by him).you than filter the query results with default $distance or one selected by user.

i used it in google maps API:https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3